# How to set innerHTML of tag inside iframe using webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<iframe>
    <html>
        <head>
        </html>
        <body>
            <blockquote>
                <p>
                "set text here"
                </p>
            </blockquote>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe
```

Hi I am trying to set innerHTML of a tag inside iframe and i can't seem to get it to work

```
textareaID.setHTML("Some Text");
```

By using runScript it writes into the textarea but it doesn't seem to write it inside the blockquote tag

```
selectFrame(iframeLocator);

sendKeys("//html/body/blockquote/p", "Some Text");
```

selectFrame selects the frame and sendKeys sends the text I want but it also doesn't write the text inside the p tag. It works fine when I run this to //html/body but it doesn't seem to work for //html/body/blockquote/p

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `<p>`

```
<p id="text">
 "set text here"
</p>
```

Place in `<head>`

```
<script>
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="some new text"
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't have the access to modify the html. I am just trying to test out the function and blockquote and p tag shows up for onclick event inside the iframe

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the FAQ [here](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_type_into_a_contentEditable_iframe?):

From the selenium wiki:

*A: Assuming that the iframe is named "foo":*

```
driver.switchTo().frame("foo");
WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
editable.sendKeys("Your text here");
```

*Sometimes this doesn't work, and this is because the iframe doesn't have any content. On Firefox you can execute the following before "sendKeys":*

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("document.body.innerHTML = '<br>'");
```

*This is needed because the iframe has no content by default: there's nothing to send keyboard input to. This method call inserts an empty tag, which sets everything up nicely. 
Remember to switch out of the frame once you're done (as all further interactions will be with this specific frame):*

> driver.switchTo().defaultContent();